# Multiple Concatenate - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Need your help -

Was able to do a concatenate for selected cells to have the value in a cell -

How to apply the same for the rest of the list ?

Thanks,
MK

```
Private Sub Trial_1_Click()
Dim CC As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim TT As String
i = 0
TT = ""
For Each CC In Selection
If i = 0 Then
i = 1
End If
TT = TT & CC.Value & ""
Next
TT = Left(TT, Len(TT))
Range("P2").Value = TT
End Sub
```

Comment: Which "list" are you referring to?

Comment: Your `i` variable is only being assigned to. It never gets used.